# Migrate to Devise in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I have an existing model that uses bcrypt to encrypt the user password.
I wonder how I could migrate to use devise?
Do I still install devise the normal way and change the model attribute via database migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add devise to your Gemfile, run `bundle install`, then `rails generate devise ModelName` (change ModelName to actual name of your model). This should add all needed things to your model as well as create a migration. I think devise will know, that your model already exists  and it won't try to create new table, but it will modify existing one instead.
Then just run `rake db:migrate`, restart server and you should be good to go.

Just to be sure, use git or some other versioning system. It's been a while since I last tried this, so make sure you can easily go back, if something goes wrong.